# Loss of accuracy with the return statement in my code

Tags: c++, return

I'm learning C++ through a great tutorial at http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/210-comprehensive-quiz As part of the quiz I need to create a calculator however the code always seems to drop the decimal. I believe that this occurs during the return statement. Anyways, any help for a newbie learning C++ is greatly appreciated. My code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int input(float);
int math(double, double, char);
void print(double);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double fNumberOne = input(0);
    double fNumberTwo = input(1);
    char Operator = input(2);
    print(math(fNumberOne, fNumberTwo, Operator));
    return 0;
}

int input(float x)
{
    using namespace std;
    if (x == 0)
    {   
        cout << "Please enter the first number" << endl;
    double input;
    cin >> input;
    return input;
    }
    if (x == 1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the second number" << endl;
        double input;
        cin >> input;
        return input;
    }
    if (x == 2)
    {
            cout << "Please enter the operator" << endl;
        char op;
        cin >> op;
        return op;
    }
}

int math(double x, double y, char op)
{
    double result(0);
    if (op == '+')
        result = x + y;
    if (op == '-')
        result = x - y;
    if (op == '/')
        result = x / y;
    if (op == 'x')
        result = x *y;
        return result;
}
void print(double x)
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are returning all of your values as integers. Try using floats or doubles.

Comment: I declared all my variables as double or char how do I make the return statement return double rather than int?

Comment: Errr... declare the function as returning one instead of an int?

Comment: hey! All your return values are ints, you have to return them as double or they will be cast and loose their decimals!

Answer (score 3):

When you return from the function `input` you are returning an `int`:

```
int input(float x)
{
    ...
    double input;
    cin >> input;
    return input; // A cast happens here to turn the double into an int.
```

You will need to return a double ie `double input(float x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your `double` is being [implicitly cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) to an `int`. Which is resulting in the following behavior:

> - A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the
>     fractional part is discarded. [...]

All you have to do is modify the return values of your functions to be a `double` rather than an `int`.

```
double input(float);
double math(double, double, char);

double input(float x)
{
  //...
}

double math(double x, double y, char op)
{
  //...
}
```